# IOS - Tab Bar Controller and Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

My storyboard structure is like this. I have problem when scene moves to my subviewcontrollers. Tab Bar disappears when scene moves to ViewController1a/2a/2b.

How can I create a permanent Tab Bar?

```
                      `NavController` --> `ViewController1` --> 'ViewController1a'
`TabBarController`--> `NavController` --> `ViewController2` --> 'ViewController2a'
                      `NavController` --> `ViewController3` --> 'ViewController2a'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this can solve your issue:

```
self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = NO;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = NO
```